# IPTables add an IP to IPSet list

Tags: iptables, ip-address, blacklist, ipset

How to correctly add an IP address to ipset from an iptables rule?
Or isn't that possible at all?

This rule doesn't work for me: `-A INPUT -m recent --name IP_LIST --set`

Type of IP_LIST is hash:net
IP_LIST was created using command `ipset create IP_LIST hash:net`

But checking the same list for an IP to drop it, works:
`-A INPUT -m set --match-set IP_LIST src -j DROP`

Comment: I don't think you understand what ipset does or is used for - -j SET is used to add an entry to an ipset.

Please consider rewording your question to explain what you overall objective is in terms of traffic filtering.

Comment: @Olipro, thank you! _-j SET_ is that I was looking for (adding an entry to ipset from an iptables rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since `-j SET` is what you wanted:

Within iptables, `-m set` is used when you want to compare a packet against an ipset (`-m` stands for match) it can be used multiple times within a single rule.

`-j SET` on the other hand is used to insert an entry into an ipset, it is a **non-terminating** target, meaning that rule traversal will continue.

You should read the iptables manpage for a full explanation of the expected syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As @Olipro and @0x534B41 said, I mustn't use `-m recent`.
So, to add an entry to ipset from an iptables rule, you should use `-j SET --add-set IPSET_LIST src`

Answer (score 0):

[Iptables documentation](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) suggests that `recent` module has nothing to do with `ipset`. Instead it creates dynamic lists which are used only by itself. The lists `recent` module uses are exposed via procfs at `/proc/net/xt_recent/`